# Formatting a pivot result by merging rows in Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **The background:**
>
> Think of an application that lets people make surveys with custom questions, In a particular case, interview families, An
>   interviewer goes to `House 1` and interviews two members `Member 1`
>   and `Member 2`. He asks questions like. *What is this house
>   address?*,*What is your name and age?*. The answers for
>   that is common for the Members and the answers that are specific for
>   them are stored in the same table

After doing some Joining on some tables and pivoting the result I end up getting the following table structure.

**What was achieved so far**

```
| ID | ADDRESS |   MEMBER |    AGE | SubformIteration  |
|----|---------|----------|--------|-------------------|
|  1 | HOUSE 1 |   (null) | (null) |    (null)         |
|  1 |  (null) | MEMBER h |     18 |         s0        |
|  1 |  (null) | MEMBER i |     19 |         s1        |
|  2 | HOUSE 2 |   (null) | (null) |    (null)         |
|  2 |  (null) | MEMBER x |     36 |         s0        |
|  2 |  (null) | MEMBER y |     35 |         s1        |
|  3 | HOUSE 3 |   (null) | (null) |    (null)         |
|  3 |  (null) | MEMBER a |     18 |         s0        |
|  3 |  (null) | MEMBER b |     19 |         s1        |
```

I am trying to find a way to get the table to be formatted as below:

**Desired output**

```
| ID | ADDRESS |   MEMBER |    AGE | SubformIteration  |
|----|---------|----------|--------|-------------------|
|  1 | HOUSE 1 | MEMBER 1 |     18 |        s0         |
|  1 | HOUSE 1 | MEMBER 2 |     19 |        s1         |
|  2 | HOUSE 2 | MEMBER x |     36 |        s0         |
|  2 | HOUSE 2 | MEMBER y |     35 |        s1         |
|  3 | HOUSE 3 | MEMBER a |     18 |        s0         |
|  3 | HOUSE 3 | MEMBER b |     19 |        s1         |
```

I do not have enough sql vocabulary to describe and search the operation/procedure required to so  As I am new to SQL and I would be really thankful if anybody could tell me an efficient way to achieve this.

**Important**

DO NOT RELY UPON THE `QuestionText` column as it will be changes When somebody decided to change the questions

**Edit**

**Source tables**

[Sql fiddle link with all the below tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eeae7/6)

As per the suggestions in the answers, I am posting the source table and the queries in hope that there will be a better understanding of the problem

`Questions` table

```
+------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------------+
| QuestionID | QuestionText |  type   | SurveyID | IsIncremental |
+------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------------+
|       3483 | subform      | subform |      311 |             1 |
|       3484 | MEMBER       | text    |      311 |             0 |
|       3485 | AGE          | number  |      311 |             0 |
|       3486 | ADDRESS      | address |      311 |             0 |
+------------+--------------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

`Results` table

```
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
| ResultID |      DateSubmitted      | SurveyID |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
|     2272 | 2017-04-12 05:11:41.477 |      311 |
|     2273 | 2017-04-12 05:12:22.227 |      311 |
|     2274 | 2017-04-12 05:13:02.227 |      311 |
+----------+-------------------------+----------+
```

`Chunks` table, where all the answers are stored:

```
+---------+------------+----------+------------+------------------+
| ChunkID |   Answer   | ResultID | QuestionID | SubFormIteration |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+------------------+
|    9606 | HOUSE 1    |     2272 |       3486 | NULL             |
|    9607 | MEMEBER 1  |     2272 |       3484 | NULL             |
|    9608 | 12         |     2272 |       3485 | NULL             |
|    9609 | MEMBER 2   |     2272 |       3484 | s1               |
|    9610 | 10         |     2272 |       3485 | s1               |
|    9611 | MEMEBER 1  |     2272 |       3484 | s0               |
|    9612 | 12         |     2272 |       3485 | s0               |
|    9613 | MEMBER 2   |     2272 |       3484 | s1               |
|    9614 | 10         |     2272 |       3485 | s1               |
|    9615 | HOUSE 2    |     2273 |       3486 | NULL             |
|    9616 | MEMBER A   |     2273 |       3484 | NULL             |
|    9617 | 23         |     2273 |       3485 | NULL             |
|    9618 | MEMBER B   |     2273 |       3484 | s1               |
|    9619 | 25         |     2273 |       3485 | s1               |
|    9620 | MEMBER A   |     2273 |       3484 | s0               |
|    9621 | 23         |     2273 |       3485 | s0               |
|    9622 | MEMBER B   |     2273 |       3484 | s1               |
|    9623 | 25         |     2273 |       3485 | s1               |
|    9624 | HOUSE 3    |     2274 |       3486 | NULL             |
|    9625 | MEMBER K   |     2274 |       3484 | NULL             |
|    9626 | 41         |     2274 |       3485 | NULL             |
|    9627 | MEMBER J   |     2274 |       3484 | s1               |
|    9628 | 26         |     2274 |       3485 | s1               |
|    9629 | MEMBER K   |     2274 |       3484 | s0               |
|    9630 | 41         |     2274 |       3485 | s0               |
|    9631 | MEMBER J   |     2274 |       3484 | s1               |
|    9632 | 26         |     2274 |       3485 | s1               |
+---------+------------+----------+------------+------------------+
```

I've written the following stored procedure which yields the first ever table given in this question:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResultForSurvey] @SurveyID int
AS
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@colsAggregated as nvarchar(max);
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #Temp;
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM (Select Answer=( case 
                    When Questions.type='checkboxes' or Questions.IsIncremental=1 THEN  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + c.Answer 
            FROM Chunks c Where c.ResultID=Results.ResultID and c.QuestionID=Questions.QuestionID and (Chunks.SubFormIteration IS NULL )
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
         else  Chunks.Answer end),Chunks.SubFormIteration,Questions.QuestionText,Questions.type,Questions.QuestionID,Chunks.ResultID,Results.ResultID as Action,Results.DateSubmitted,Results.Username,Results.SurveyID from Chunks Join Questions on Questions.QuestionID= Chunks.QuestionID Join Results on Results.ResultID=Chunks.ResultID Where Results.SurveyID=@SurveyID) as X


SET @colsAggregated = STUFF((SELECT distinct ','+ 'max('+ QUOTENAME(c.QuestionText)+') as '+ QUOTENAME(c.QuestionText)
            FROM #Temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')
        print @colsAggregated
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.QuestionText) 
            FROM #Temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT ResultID,max(Username) as Username,max(DateSubmitted) as DateSubmitted,max(SubFormIteration) as SubFormIteration, ' + @colsAggregated + ' from 
            (
                select * 
                from #Temp
           ) as y
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Answer)
                for QuestionText in (' + @cols + ')
            ) as p GROUP BY 
    ResultID,SubFormIteration'
execute(@query)
```

Comment: for sure we need more info how another batch of data looks/ Is there HOUSE 2 fallowing rows? U showed only 3 rows, we have too little data to be sure what You want to do.

Comment: I agree I have added the need and background for the operation, But cannot add the source data as it requires to be selected using multiple joins from several  tables,Hope it helps you to understand the problem here

Comment: How do you associate responses (like age) between Members? For example, for ResultId 2272, how do I know whether Member 1's age is 10 or 12. Perhaps the SubFormIteration tells you this?

Comment: Yes,Using the column 'SubformIteration' and 'ResultID'

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: is your table input and desire output in tandem ?can you please reexplain only your desire output data asap. ?

Comment: The desired output is the 2nd table in the question, The 1st table is what I have achieved so far with the stored procedure. The source tables are the preceding tables after 2nd in the question

Comment: The SQL fiddle link isn't working.

Comment: what is desired output and which is source table is clear.But biz rule of of desire output not clear.most importantly I am not seeing any of the value in desired output in source table for example House 1,House 2,age etc.where are they in your source table.

Comment: Sorry, The source table has been edited

Answer (score 4):

It may be beneficial to post the query that got you your original results; there is a possibility that the original query could be rewritten to avoid this complexity. With the given information, this is the most simplistic way of solving this problem:

```
SELECT
   h1.Id,
   h2.Address,
   h1.Member,
   h1.Age,
   h1.MemberNo
FROM House h1
  INNER JOIN House h2
  ON h1.Id = h2.Id
WHERE h2.Address IS NOT NULL  -- Eliminates the results whre the Address is NULL after the join
  AND h1.Member IS NOT NULL -- Eliminates the results that would show up from the original table (t1) where there is no Member field
```

## Update:

Here is a simple example of the table structure using temp tables:

```
DROP TABLE #Questions
DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #Chunks

CREATE TABLE #Questions
(
  QuestionId INT,
  QuestionText VARCHAR(MAX),
  type VARCHAR(MAX),
  SurveyID INT,
  IsIncremental INT
)

CREATE TABLE #Results
(
    ResultId INT,
    DateSubmitted DATETIME,
    SurveyID INT
)

CREATE TABLE #Chunks
(
    ChunkId INT,
    Answer VARCHAR(MAX),
    ResultId INT,
    QuestionId INT,
    SubFormIteration VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Results
VALUES (2272, '04-12-2017', 311),
(2273, '04-12-2017', 311),
(2274, '04-12-2017', 311)

INSERT INTO #Chunks
VALUES (9606, 'WhiteHouse', 2272, 3486, NULL),
(9607, 'MEMBER 1', 2272, 3484, NULL),
(9608, '12', 2272, 3485, NULL),
(9609, 'MEMBER 2', 2272, 3484, 's1'),
(9610, '10', 2272, 3485, 's1'),
(9611, 'MEMBER 1', 2272, 3484, 's0'),
(9612, '12', 2272, 3485, 's0'),
(9613, 'MEMBER 2', 2272, 3484, 's1'),
(9614, '10', 2272, 3485, 's1'),
(9615, 'RpBhavan', 2273, 3486, NULL),
(9618, 'MEMBER B', 2273, 3484, 's1'),
(9619, '25', 2273, 3485, 's1'),
(9620, 'MEMBER A', 2273, 3484, 's0'),
(9621, '23', 2273, 3485, 's0')

INSERT INTO #Questions
VALUES (3483, 'subform', 'subform', 311, 1),
( 3484, 'MEMBER', 'text', 311, 0 ),
(3485, 'AGE', 'number', 311, 0),
(3486, 'ADDRESS', 'address', 311, 0)
```

Here is a way to produce the results your looking for without the use of PIVOTs and XML:

```
; WITH Responses AS (
SELECT
    c.ResultId,
    QuestionText,
    Answer,
    c.SubFormIteration
FROM #Chunks c
    INNER JOIN #Results r
    ON c.ResultId = r.ResultId
    INNER JOIN #Questions q
    ON q.QuestionId = c.QuestionId
WHERE c.SubFormIteration IS NOT NULL -- Removes the "Address" responses and duplicate Answers
),
FindAddress AS (
-- Pulls ONLY the address for each ResultId
SELECT
    ResultId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionText = 'ADDRESS' THEN Answer END) AS [Address]
FROM #Chunks c
    INNER JOIN #Questions q
    ON q.QuestionId = c.QuestionId
GROUP BY ResultId
)
-- Combines all responses and the address back together
SELECT
    r.ResultId,
    fa.Address,
    MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionText = 'MEMBER' THEN Answer END) AS [MEMBER],
    MAX(CASE WHEN QuestionText = 'AGE' THEN Answer END) AS [Age],
    SubFormIteration
FROM Responses r
    INNER JOIN FindAddress fa
    ON fa.ResultId = r.ResultId
GROUP BY r.ResultId, SubFormIteration, fa.Address
```

Essentially, I broke a rather large query into a Common Table Expression (CTE). Each query had a purpose: a) Response pulls all responses *except* the address, b) Pulls only the address based on ResultId, and c) Combine both queries together.

The MAX(CASE...) followed by GROUP BY is an alternative method to using PIVOTS and they essentially perform the same.

To apply this query to your specific case, you should only need to change the name of the tables.

Comment: I have added the original result and the query, Please go through it when you are available

Comment: Thank you for the response,I can see that you have 'hardcoded' the QuestionTexts in the CASE statements, but the problem with this is content in the QuestionText is entirely different each time, Do you have a solution for that without using a hardcoded QuestionText?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand: you want to do this dynamically. For this you need to prepare the question text and run it.

The columns are being prepared. Then merged with the query.

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = 'C.ResultId' +
           (
                SELECT
                    ',' +       
                    CASE WHEN COL.QuestionText = 'ADDRESS' THEN 'MAX(AA.Answer)' +  COL.QuestionText
                    ELSE 'MAX(CASE WHEN Q.QuestionText = ''' + COL.QuestionText  + ''' THEN C.Answer ELSE  '''' END) AS ' +  COL.QuestionText END
                FROM 
                    #Questions COL
                WHERE
                    COL.QuestionText != 'subform'       
                FOR XML PATH ('')
           ) + 
           ',MAX(C.SubFormIteration) AS SubFormIteration'

SET @Query = '
           SELECT ' +
                @Columns +
         ' FROM 
               #Chunks C INNER JOIN 
               #Results R ON C.ResultId = R.ResultId INNER JOIN 
               #Questions Q ON Q.QuestionId = C.QuestionId INNER JOIN
               (
                    SELECT 
                        IC.ResultId,
                        MAX(IC.Answer) AS Answer
                    FROM 
                       #Chunks IC INNER JOIN 
                       #Results IR ON IC.ResultId = IR.ResultId INNER JOIN 
                       #Questions IQ ON IQ.QuestionId = IC.QuestionId 
                    WHERE
                        IQ.QuestionText = ''ADDRESS''
                    GROUP BY
                        IC.ResultId

               ) AA ON C.ResultId = AA.ResultId
            WHERE
               C.SubFormIteration IS NOT NULL                   
             GROUP BY   
               C.ResultId,       
               C.SubFormIteration           
             '
--SELECT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Output:

```
ResultId    MEMBER      AGE  ADDRESS      SubFormIteration
----------- ----------- ---- ------------ --------------------
2272        MEMBER 1    12   WhiteHouse   s0
2272        MEMBER 2    10   WhiteHouse   s1
2273        MEMBER A    23   RpBhavan     s0
2273        MEMBER B    25   RpBhavan     s1
```

**For Comment:**

Columns "ResultId" and "SubFormIteration" are grouped and the result is. But the grouping operation is incorrect because the address information looks like this. The query and result are below.

```
ResultId    MEMBER       AGE      ADDRESS      SubFormIteration
----------- -------------------------------------------------------
2272        MEMBER 1     12       WhiteHouse   NULL -- Which value you want to group. s1 or s0
2272        MEMBER 1     12                    s0
2272        MEMBER 2     10                    s1
2273                              RpBhavan     NULL -- Which value you want to group. s1 or s0
2273        MEMBER A     23                    s0
2273        MEMBER B     25
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = 'C.ResultId' +
           (
                SELECT
                    ',' +                           
                    'MAX(CASE WHEN Q.QuestionText = ''' + COL.QuestionText  + ''' THEN C.Answer ELSE  '''' END) AS ' +  COL.QuestionText
                FROM 
                    #Questions COL
                WHERE
                    COL.QuestionText != 'subform'       
                FOR XML PATH ('')
           ) + 
           ',MAX(C.SubFormIteration
           ) AS SubFormIteration'

SET @Query = '
           SELECT ' +
                @Columns +
         ' FROM 
               #Chunks C INNER JOIN 
               #Results R ON C.ResultId = R.ResultId INNER JOIN 
               #Questions Q ON Q.QuestionId = C.QuestionId                              
             GROUP BY   
               C.ResultId,       
               C.SubFormIteration           
             '
--SELECT @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Why would you use QuestionText such as 'ADDRESS'  or 'subform' if you know that they are dynamic?

Comment: There is a special case for the address. The address does not have `SubFormIteration` info (SubFormIteration IS NULL). If you can assign a SubFormIteration value to the address, you can remove it.

Comment: And If it has a value, How will it change the query

Answer (score 2):

We can't see your input query, but my guess is that you're getting those null columns because of a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` join in your source query. If you could split your result vertically into two views like this:

```
| ID | ADDRESS |
|----|---------|
|  1 | HOUSE 1 |
```

and

```
| ID |  MEMBER  |    AGE | MEMBERNO |
|----|----------|--------|----------|
|  1 | MEMBER 1 |     18 |        1 |
|  1 | MEMBER 2 |     19 |        2 |
```

and then join them on `ID` field, you'll get precisely the result you need.

### Edit

After looking at your edit, here is how you apply the above method in your scenario:

First query:

```
SELECT ID, ADDRESS FROM YourTable WHERE ADDRESS IS NOT NULL
```

Second query:

```
SELECT MEMBER, AGE, MEMBERNO WHERE MEMBER IS NOT NULL AND AGE IS NOT NULL AND MEMBERNO IS NOT NULL
```

Now join them together on `ID`:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT ID, ADDRESS FROM YourTable WHERE ADDRESS IS NOT NULL) AS A
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT MEMBER, AGE, MEMBERNO WHERE MEMBER IS NOT NULL AND AGE IS NOT NULL AND MEMBERNO IS NOT NULL) AS B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: Please check out question edit and confirm if this method is applicable in this scenario

Comment: I have added the original result and the query, Please go through it when you are available

Answer (score 2):

If the above table is a result of multiple joins/etc, it would be better if we could give a recommendation based on the actual schema available to you. However, if the sample table in the SQL Fiddle link is all you have to work with, try the following:

```
SELECT h.address, p.member, p.age, p.memberno
FROM House h
     INNER JOIN
       House p 
       ON h.id = p.id
         AND h.member IS NULL
         AND p.member IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I have added the original result and the query, Please go through it when you are available

Answer (score 1):

By Looking Of Your Answer i think you need result of `CROSS JOIN` of Two Table

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * from table1,table2
```

This will help you...